# .htaccess: how to write rule for matching url, then match url with parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am newbie to htaccess rules, I want to make a rule for redirecting these URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^news$ index.php?r=news [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/$ index.php?r=news [QSA]
```

the `news` url is an index page of some articles, so to access an article I wrote these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([/s/S])$ index.php?r=news/p&id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([/s/S])/$ index.php?r=news/p&id=$1 [QSA]
```

the first rule (for the `news` index) is working correctly, but the other rules doesn't work, what is the problem?

Comment: You must have meant `[\s\S]*`, not `[/s/S]`. But it seems to me the newlines should not be there, just use `.*`. It also seems to me the first rule will match what the second rule is supposed to match, swap them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: I "converted" the comment into an answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have meant `[\s\S]*` (= zero or more characters including a newline), not `[/s/S]`. It seems to me the newlines should not be present in URLs, that is why you can safely use `.*` instead.

Also, the first rule will match what the second rule is supposed to match (as the `.*` is matching any characters but a newline, it will match the final `/`, too), thus you need swap them.

Comment: That worked for me too. +1 for the  king of Regexxxx :)